# How to reference join table columns from a rails index.html.erb view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 Rails 4.2 tables: books, tags, categorizations where categorizations is a many to many join table for the other two.

Inside the show.html.erb file, I can say

```
<%= @categorization.book.title %>
```

and the book title will be displayed, but inside index.html.erb, if I say something similar like

```
<%= categorizations.each do |categorization| %>
<%= categorization.book_id %> # this is ok
<%= categorization.book.title %> # not ok
 ...
<% end %>
```

The error message is

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClas
```

I'm sure there is a way to get rails to do this, but I am not doing it right.  Is there a way to ask the controller to do a join using all three tables instead of just the join table?  Or do I need to instantiate a book object inside the loop (sounds ugly, but ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing the ActiveRecord Associations in your models.  In order to have a `book` accessor on your `categorization` model, you would need to define the association in the models.  From what you say above, it sounds like you would want to create a `has_many :through` association.

See the [Active Record Associations documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) for more details.  I imagine it would look something like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :tags, through: :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :books, through: :categorizations
end
```

Once you have the associations in place, you should be able to do `@categorization.book` without issue.

Comment: class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :tags, :through => :categorizations

Comment: class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base has_many :categorizations has_many :books, :through => :categorizations

Comment: class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :book belongs_to :tag end

Comment: Basically, my models look just as you suggest.  I don't think the show.html.erb would work if the models or the database was wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question above with the summarized version of your models for future people to see.  If your models are setup correctly (and you can confirm this in the rails console by loading a categorization and successfully accessing the book for it), then it sounds like your categorization has an invalid book_id (so the book accessor returns nil).

Comment: Brian, you were completely right.  I copied the database and cut down the data in database to make sure that it was consistent and now the error is gone.  Next I will go back to the original database and look for the bad data.  I am going to up vote your answer.  Thanks for your help.